# how to define my artifact groupId?

Tags: sbt

I have an sbt project that I need publish-local and then use it from an other project as a "libraryDependencies". It all builds fine but the groupId of the artifact is the same as the name of it. Can I specify the groupId somehow in my build.sbt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is `organization` setting for this purpose.
An example from [AkkaBuild.scala](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/AkkaBuild.scala)

```
lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    organization        := "com.typesafe.akka",
    version             := "2.4-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion        := Dependencies.Versions.scalaVersion,
    crossScalaVersions  := Dependencies.Versions.crossScala
  )
```